How to bind UUIDs as VARCHAR parameter in a native query?
I'm adding a new column - uuid with varchar(36) type in Oracle DB.
I had a search query that searched by ids, now I need to add a similar query but using uuids instead.
@Column(name = "UUID")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
var uuid: UUID? = null

JPA Query:
    @Query(
        """
            SELECT 
            t.id,
            t.uuid,
...
            FROM my_table t
            START WITH t.uuid in (:uuids)
            CONNECT BY PRIOR t.parent_id = t.id
        """,
        nativeQuery = true
    )
fun getMyEntitiesByUuids(uuids: List<UUID>): List<MyEntity>      

But uuids are bind as Binary:
binding parameter [1] as [BINARY] - [00440c26-219d-4a81-adb9-9c16f617bffb]

and result set is empty.
Running this query directly with uuids passed in quotes returns expected result set.
How can I declare the parameter for it to be bind as VARCHAR?

uuid-char is provider-specific and it seems like Oracle translates it into their native UUID type which is raw(16).
For Hibernate 6+, you can try using @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.CHAR) instead, or set spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type.preferred_uuid_jdbc_type=CHAR.
For older versions, this question recommends an AttributeConverter<UUID, String>

I have an older version (5.4.32). AttributeConverter had the same effect as @Type. Unfortunately, it didn't help with a native query
